Hide Individual payment methods Place Order buttons from magento 2 checkout page
I don't want to show place order button two times i.e. common place order button and under each payment method. So I just want to hide the place order button of individual payment methods and keep the common place order button. How can I hide the individual place order button of each payment method ?

Hey, In some payment methods that have payment/pay now buttons which handles payment flow of particular payment gateway/ iframe, etc so you don't hide that button that may not be recommended, simply in this case you can hide simple(common) place order button. Thank You!
